# Fitnesse : "could not detect death of command line test runner"

Tags: java, spring, maven, fitnesse

Each time we launch a fitnesse test, it ends by saying

> Testing was interrupted and results are incomplete

And we have an exception :

```
Could not detect death of command line test runner.
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited
    at fitnesse.components.CommandRunner.join(CommandRunner.java:79)
    at fitnesse.responders.run.slimResponder.SlimTestSystem.bye(SlimTestSystem.java:208)
    at fitnesse.responders.run.MultipleTestsRunner.startTestSystemAndExecutePages(MultipleTestsRunner.java:118)
    at fitnesse.responders.run.MultipleTestsRunner.internalExecuteTestPages(MultipleTestsRunner.java:88)
    at fitnesse.responders.run.MultipleTestsRunner.executeTestPages(MultipleTestsRunner.java:60)
    at fitnesse.responders.run.TestResponder.performExecution(TestResponder.java:190)
    at fitnesse.responders.run.TestResponder.doExecuteTests(TestResponder.java:72)
    at fitnesse.responders.run.TestResponder$TestExecutor.execute(TestResponder.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.doInvoke(UberspectImpl.java:395)
    at org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:384)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:173)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:280)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.render(ASTReference.java:369)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:342)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Parse.render(Parse.java:260)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTDirective.render(ASTDirective.java:207)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:342)
    at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:356)
    at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:260)
    at fitnesse.responders.templateUtilities.HtmlPage.render(HtmlPage.java:80)
    at fitnesse.responders.run.TestResponder.doSending(TestResponder.java:61)
    at fitnesse.responders.ChunkingResponder.startSending(ChunkingResponder.java:66)
    at fitnesse.http.ChunkedResponse.sendTo(ChunkedResponse.java:26)
    at fitnesse.FitNesseExpediter.sendResponse(FitNesseExpediter.java:96)
    at fitnesse.FitNesseExpediter.start(FitNesseExpediter.java:48)
    at fitnesse.FitNesseServer.serve(FitNesseServer.java:24)
    at fitnesse.FitNesseServer.serve(FitNesseServer.java:17)
    at fitnesse.socketservice.SocketService$ServerRunner.run(SocketService.java:109)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
```

Have you encountered the same problem ? How did you solved it ?

fitnesse version : 20121220

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that you have a class reference that is hanging out there and that FitNesse cannot close.  Or something is calling System.exit().

An example of the first is Selenium WebDriver.  You must close() the browserDriver to get a clean end to a test.

The second is something that we unintentionally allowed in the past and has been changed in more recent releases. It's possible that updating to the latest EDGE might solve it.

However, more context is really required, as this is quite likely an issue in your configuration or your fixture.